# Set 0 instead of NULL value with Pivot

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have a request with pivot and when it return ONE value, it show only one value and not all the line in a table..
I would like that if he don't find all the value he return all the lines and not only the lines where there is a value.
Here's the code :

```
DECLARE @P_A_USER VARCHAR(10)
SET @P_A_USER = 'BBE' -- Here with the user BBE

set language us_english
select * from (
select datename(month, D1) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Total_nouveaux_contrats', 'Nouveaux contrats' as 'Donnee', 'a' as 'NumLigne' from CONTRAT
where C22 = @P_A_USER and year(D1) = year(getdate()) and C27 = 01
group by datename(month, D1)) as NvContrats


Pivot(
SUM(Total_nouveaux_contrats)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt1
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, D1) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Total_contrats_renew_1an_perim', 'Renew 1 an avec modification périmètre et FI 30%' as 'Donnee', 'b' as 'NumLigne' from CONTRAT
where C22 = @P_A_USER and year(D1) = year(getdate()) and C27 = 02
group by datename(month, D1)) as NvContrats


Pivot(
SUM(Total_contrats_renew_1an_perim)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt2
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, D1) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Total_contrats_renew_1an', 'Renew 1 an sans modification périmètre' as 'Donnee', 'c' as 'NumLigne' from CONTRAT
where C22 = @P_A_USER and year(D1) = year(getdate()) and C27 = 03
group by datename(month, D1)) as NvContrats


Pivot(
SUM(Total_contrats_renew_1an)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt3
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, D1) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Total_contrats_renew_3ans', 'Renew 3 ans sans modification périmètre' as 'Donnee', 'd' as 'NumLigne' from CONTRAT
where C22 = @P_A_USER and year(D1) = year(getdate()) and C27 = 04
group by datename(month, D1)) as NvContrats


Pivot(
SUM(Total_contrats_renew_3ans)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt4
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DAT_ACT_PA) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'RDV_realises', 'RDV réalisés' as 'Donnee', 'e' as 'NumLigne' from ACTION
where COD_COM = @P_A_USER and CO_T_CO_PA = 'RDVCL' and year(DAT_ACT_PA) = year(getdate())
group by datename(month, DAT_ACT_PA)) as RDVrealise


Pivot(
SUM(RDV_realises)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt5
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DAT_ACT_PR) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'RDV_planifies', 'RDV planifiés' as 'Donnee', 'f' as 'NumLigne' from ACTION
where COD_COM = @P_A_USER and CO_T_CO_PA = 'RDVCL' and year(DAT_ACT_PR) = year(getdate()) and DAT_ACT_PA is NULL
group by datename(month, DAT_ACT_PR)) as RDVplanifie


Pivot(
SUM(RDV_planifies)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt6
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DATE_COMMANDE) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(distinct SOCIETE.NO_SOCIETE), 0) as 'Nouveaux_comptes', 'Nouveaux comptes ouverts' as 'Donnee', 'g' as 'NumLigne' from SOCIETE
left join V_COMMANDE on V_COMMANDE.NO_SOCIETE = SOCIETE.NO_SOCIETE
where SOCIETE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(DATE_COMMANDE) = year(getdate()) and (SOCIETE.CA = 0 and SOCIETE.CAN_1 = 0)
group by datename(month, DATE_COMMANDE)) as NvComptes


Pivot(
SUM(Nouveaux_comptes)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt7
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, CREER_LE) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Nouvelles_affaires', 'Nouvelles affaires' as 'Donnee', 'h' as 'NumLigne' from AFFAIRE
where AFFAIRE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(CREER_LE) = year(getdate())
group by datename(month, CREER_LE)) as NvAffaires


Pivot(
SUM(Nouvelles_affaires)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt8
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DATE_AFF) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Nouvelles_affaires_exploitation', 'Nouvelles affaires avec exploitation' as 'Donnee', 'i' as 'NumLigne' from AFFAIRE
where AFFAIRE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(DATE_AFF) = year(getdate()) and N3 != 0
group by datename(month, DATE_AFF)) as NvAffairesExp


Pivot(
SUM(Nouvelles_affaires_exploitation)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt9
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DATE_AFF) as 'Mois', cast(COALESCE(SUM(N1), 0) as integer) as 'CA_nouvelles_affaires', 'CA nouvelles affaires (€)' as 'Donnee', 'j' as 'NumLigne' from AFFAIRE
where AFFAIRE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(CREER_LE) = year(getdate())
group by datename(month, DATE_AFF)) as CaNvAffaires


Pivot(
SUM(CA_nouvelles_affaires)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt10
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DATE_AFF) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Nb_affaires_gagnees', 'Affaires gagnées' as 'Donnee', 'k' as 'NumLigne' from AFFAIRE
where AFFAIRE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(DATE_AFF) = year(getdate()) and COD_ETAT = 02
group by datename(month, DATE_AFF)) as NbAffG


Pivot(
SUM(Nb_affaires_gagnees)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt11
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DATE_AFF) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Nb_affaires_perdues', 'Affaires perdues' as 'Donnee', 'l' as 'NumLigne' from AFFAIRE
where AFFAIRE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(DATE_AFF) = year(getdate()) and COD_ETAT = 03
group by datename(month, DATE_AFF)) as NbAffP


Pivot(
SUM(Nb_affaires_perdues)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt12

order by NumLigne asc
```

That's the result with the user BBE :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2rKE.jpg

I would like him to give me all the lines and put 0 in place of the Null ...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is not MySQL code.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

```
Did you use 0 as char or as number


DECLARE @P_A_USER VARCHAR(10)
SET @P_A_USER = 'BBE' -- Here with the user BBE

set language us_english
select * from (
select datename(month, D1) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), '0') as 'Total_nouveaux_contrats', 'Nouveaux contrats' as 'Donnee', 'a' as 'NumLigne' from CONTRAT
where C22 = @P_A_USER and year(D1) = year(getdate()) and C27 = 01
group by datename(month, D1)) as NvContrats


Pivot(
SUM(Total_nouveaux_contrats)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt1
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, D1) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Total_contrats_renew_1an_perim', 'Renew 1 an avec modification périmètre et FI 30%' as 'Donnee', 'b' as 'NumLigne' from CONTRAT
where C22 = @P_A_USER and year(D1) = year(getdate()) and C27 = 02
group by datename(month, D1)) as NvContrats


Pivot(
SUM(Total_contrats_renew_1an_perim)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt2
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, D1) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Total_contrats_renew_1an', 'Renew 1 an sans modification périmètre' as 'Donnee', 'c' as 'NumLigne' from CONTRAT
where C22 = @P_A_USER and year(D1) = year(getdate()) and C27 = 03
group by datename(month, D1)) as NvContrats


Pivot(
SUM(Total_contrats_renew_1an)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt3
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, D1) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Total_contrats_renew_3ans', 'Renew 3 ans sans modification périmètre' as 'Donnee', 'd' as 'NumLigne' from CONTRAT
where C22 = @P_A_USER and year(D1) = year(getdate()) and C27 = 04
group by datename(month, D1)) as NvContrats


Pivot(
SUM(Total_contrats_renew_3ans)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt4
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DAT_ACT_PA) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'RDV_realises', 'RDV réalisés' as 'Donnee', 'e' as 'NumLigne' from ACTION
where COD_COM = @P_A_USER and CO_T_CO_PA = 'RDVCL' and year(DAT_ACT_PA) = year(getdate())
group by datename(month, DAT_ACT_PA)) as RDVrealise


Pivot(
SUM(RDV_realises)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt5
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DAT_ACT_PR) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'RDV_planifies', 'RDV planifiés' as 'Donnee', 'f' as 'NumLigne' from ACTION
where COD_COM = @P_A_USER and CO_T_CO_PA = 'RDVCL' and year(DAT_ACT_PR) = year(getdate()) and DAT_ACT_PA is NULL
group by datename(month, DAT_ACT_PR)) as RDVplanifie


Pivot(
SUM(RDV_planifies)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt6
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DATE_COMMANDE) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(distinct SOCIETE.NO_SOCIETE), 0) as 'Nouveaux_comptes', 'Nouveaux comptes ouverts' as 'Donnee', 'g' as 'NumLigne' from SOCIETE
left join V_COMMANDE on V_COMMANDE.NO_SOCIETE = SOCIETE.NO_SOCIETE
where SOCIETE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(DATE_COMMANDE) = year(getdate()) and (SOCIETE.CA = 0 and SOCIETE.CAN_1 = 0)
group by datename(month, DATE_COMMANDE)) as NvComptes


Pivot(
SUM(Nouveaux_comptes)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt7
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, CREER_LE) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Nouvelles_affaires', 'Nouvelles affaires' as 'Donnee', 'h' as 'NumLigne' from AFFAIRE
where AFFAIRE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(CREER_LE) = year(getdate())
group by datename(month, CREER_LE)) as NvAffaires


Pivot(
SUM(Nouvelles_affaires)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt8
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DATE_AFF) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Nouvelles_affaires_exploitation', 'Nouvelles affaires avec exploitation' as 'Donnee', 'i' as 'NumLigne' from AFFAIRE
where AFFAIRE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(DATE_AFF) = year(getdate()) and N3 != 0
group by datename(month, DATE_AFF)) as NvAffairesExp


Pivot(
SUM(Nouvelles_affaires_exploitation)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt9
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DATE_AFF) as 'Mois', cast(COALESCE(SUM(N1), 0) as integer) as 'CA_nouvelles_affaires', 'CA nouvelles affaires (€)' as 'Donnee', 'j' as 'NumLigne' from AFFAIRE
where AFFAIRE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(CREER_LE) = year(getdate())
group by datename(month, DATE_AFF)) as CaNvAffaires


Pivot(
SUM(CA_nouvelles_affaires)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt10
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DATE_AFF) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Nb_affaires_gagnees', 'Affaires gagnées' as 'Donnee', 'k' as 'NumLigne' from AFFAIRE
where AFFAIRE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(DATE_AFF) = year(getdate()) and COD_ETAT = 02
group by datename(month, DATE_AFF)) as NbAffG


Pivot(
SUM(Nb_affaires_gagnees)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt11
UNION
select * from (
select datename(month, DATE_AFF) as 'Mois', COALESCE(count(*), 0) as 'Nb_affaires_perdues', 'Affaires perdues' as 'Donnee', 'l' as 'NumLigne' from AFFAIRE
where AFFAIRE.COD_COM = @P_A_USER and year(DATE_AFF) = year(getdate()) and COD_ETAT = 03
group by datename(month, DATE_AFF)) as NbAffP


Pivot(
SUM(Nb_affaires_perdues)
for Mois in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) as pvt12

order by NumLigne asc
```

Comment: I use 0 as a number

Comment: I tried to replace all the COALESCE 0 with COALESCE '0' and I have the same result ..